# Strange GET/POST requests in firebug

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, firebug

I have just started a MVC project and I faced with a very strange behavior.
When I run it it displays me some empty Home/Index
But when I go to firebug I see tens of very strange and endless requests, like this one:

GET http://  localhost  :58567/3a5679dd22ba46d1993...%00101+Firefox%2F33.0&tid=7&_=1417193472430
And such the requests go one after another one and don't stop, although I don't trigger any action.

I don't understand where they come from. My app does not send any request and previously I've never faced with such the behavior. In my previous experience firebug showed me only the requests I made.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

These requests come from the "Browser Link" feature in Visual Studio, they're not something you'll have manually added. There's more detail on the feature at http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link , including how to disable it if you don't need it.